# What is package textured_object_detection used for?

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder about the package textured_object_detection. It's description says it has a similar purpose to tod_detecting, though there has been much more activity on tod_detecting recently.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9692/what-is-package-textured_object_detection-used-for?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is an older version of tod_detecting. Yes, we are aware it is a mess. We are doing a lot of cleaning behind the scene and plan on releasing that in July/August.
For now, tod_training/detecting should be used.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) on 2011-06-17**:
Was this the package where the detection was textured, as opposed to the objects detected?

**Comment by [ethanrublee](https://answers.ros.org/users/200/ethanrublee/) on 2011-06-17**:
It is my recommendation that you should wait for the July/August release of object recognition.